# Why a rotating ball (at the end of a rope) does not fall down?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Is the explanation shown in the diagram right?

[image: Diagram]

This is: the net force F1 = tangential + tension is way much bigger than the weight of the ball and, therefore, the resulting force F1 + weight is F1 so that the ball does not fall down.

**UPDATE**
Thank you very much for your answers.

Actual situation:

[image]

Comment: There is no tangential force, just tangential speed which is outcome of centripetal tension force.

Comment: No, it is incorrect. Assuming *uniform rotational motion*, then there's no $F_{tangential}$, because there's no tangential acceleration. Also, are you aware that the object and the centre of the circle can never lie in the same horizontal plane?

Comment: This is the *Conical pendulum*. If vertical height between suspension point and horizontal rotation plane is $h$ , then $ g= \omega^2 \; h$

Comment: How is the hand script sketch made? @cibercitizen1

Comment: @Narasimham With GoodNotes

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas  If there is no $F_{tangential}$ then, what force opposes to $F_{tension}$ so that the ball is not pulled to the center, but follows a circular path? Moreover the accelerations $a_c = w^2 r$ applied to the mass of the ball is a force. What's the vector (where does it points) of this force?

Comment: @Ger Please, see my comment to AgniusVasiliauskas

Comment: $F_{tangential}$ would not prevent the ball from being pulled to the center (assume it was$> 0$), because it isn't radial.

Comment: @Gert I suppose you are true, but I considered at the "differential level (tending to 0)" the sum of $F_{T}$ with the hypothetical $F_{tangential}$ and it made sense to me, as the net result appeared to be what makes the ball to follow the circular path. This is, if $T_y$ is against weight $mg$ and $T_x$ is against a radial outward force (that comes from ...?), then what makes the ball spin?

Comment: *is against a radial outward force (that comes from ...?)* It's the centrifugal force. What makes the ball spin? *Initially* forces acted to make it spin. But in *uniform rotation* there are no **NET** forces acting on it (see Newton's 2nd Law) any more. $F_{tangential} \neq 0$ is only true if $v_{tangential} \neq 0$ (non-uniform rotation)

Comment: @Gert, centrifugal force? is it not a fake force? Or it must considered in this precise frame of reference?

Comment: It is Real in the correct frame of reference (one that rotates *with* the ball) It is this FoR that's used to calculate string tension and angle of string with the horizontal.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to spin a ball about a vertical axis using a string, it would never rise up to a level above the horizontal level. In fact the angle upto which it will rise could also be calculated. Suppose the length of the string is $l$ and at equilibrium the angle it makes with the vertical axis is $\theta$, $\omega$ be the angular velocity of the axis, and the tension in the string is $T$. Then, we have:
$$T\cos \theta =mg$$

$$T\sin \theta =m{\omega}^2 l\sin\theta $$
From these two equations, we have:
$$\cos\theta=\frac {g}{{\omega}^2 l}$$
Clearly, if $\omega\to \infty$, $\theta\to 90°$, which means $\theta$ can never exceed $90°$. Also note that $w>\sqrt {\frac gl}$ is required if ball is to rise up even a little.

Comment: Actually, it cannot reach $90^{\circ}$ either. That would indeed require $\omega \to \infty$.

Comment: True, that's why I wrote that $\theta {\to 90°}$ instead of $\theta=90°$

Comment: I came to theses equations too. But I need to understand the diagram of forces. $ T sin( \theta)$ is the x projection/component of T (tension). The right hand of that equation $m \omega^2 r sin(\theta)$ is also a force. Then, must I assume that is in the opposite direction than $T_x$? Why?

Comment: Can someone comment about what is wrong in the following when PE and KE are equated? $h$ is height of the rotating conical pendulum.  $ mg h (\sec \theta-1) = \frac12m(\omega h \tan \theta)^2\to \omega^2= \dfrac{g}{h} \dfrac{2 \cos \theta}{1+ \cos \theta}$   which is valid only for small $\theta?$.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 not at all. $\omega^2 r$ is the centripetal acceleration.